# Converting a for loop into a while loop (java)

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I need to convert a for-loop into a while-loop.

Here is the for-loop:

```
double price;
for (int person = 1; person <= 20; person++){
     for (int day = 1; day <= 10; day++){
          price = 2.5;
          price = price * person * day;
          System.out.print("\t" + price);
     }
     System.out.println();
}
```

Here is what I tried:

```
double price = 2.5;
int person = 1;
while (person <= 20){
      int day = 1;
      while (day <= 10) {
           price *= person * day;
           System.out.print("\t" + price);
           day++;
      }
      System.out.println();
      person++;
}
```

However, I do not get the same output. Could someone help me with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've got `price` inside a nested loop and the second time - outside. The equivalent would be:

```
int person = 1;
while (person <= 20){
      int day = 1;
      while (day <= 10) {
           double price = 2.5;
           price *= person * day;
           System.out.print("\t" + price);
           day++;
      }
      System.out.println();
      person++;
}
```

P.S.: Introducing a variable on every loop turn does not make much sense, why not inlining it: `System.out.print("\t" + (2.5 * person * day));`?